# problem doing user command in arrays in c++ consol

Tags: c++

I want to receive a command from user like

```
sum s13:h17
```

and calculate the amount of

```
arr[12][18] + arr[16][6]
```

a to t count as 1 to 20 for columns and put it into the array that user enter in the beginning of program why this code wont work?

```
arr[x-1][y -1] = arr[(str[5] - '1' ) + (str[6] - '1') + 10][str[4] - 'a'] + arr[(str[9] - '1' )+ (str[10] - '1') + 10][str[8] - 'a'];
```

it only works for strlen(str)==9 
this if is in a while loop my code :

```
if (str[0] == 's') {
            if (strlen(str)==9)
                arr[x-1][y-1]= arr[str[5] - '1'][str[4] - 'a'] + arr[str[8] - '1'][str[7] - 'a'];
            system("cls");
            print(arr);
            continue;

            if(strlen(str)==11)

                arr[x-1][y -1] = arr[(str[5] - '1' ) + (str[6] - '1') + 10]
                [str[4] - 'a'] + arr[(str[9] - '1' ) + (str[10] - '1') + 10][str[8] - 'a'];
            system("cls");
            print(arr);
            continue;

            if (strlen(str) == 10)

                if(str[6]==':')
                arr[x - 1][y - 1] = arr[str[5] - '1'][str[4] - 'a']
                 + arr[(str[8] - '1') + ((str[9] - '1') + 10)][str[7] - 'a'];

                else {
                    arr[x - 1][y - 1] = arr[(str[5] - '1') + (str[6] - '1') + 10][str[4] - 'a']
                        + arr[str[9] - '1'][str[8] - 'a'];
                }

            system("cls");
            print(arr);
            continue;

        }
```

Comment: What is `str`? Anyway `str[5] - '1'` is probably wrong. Also please specify _what_  is not working.

Comment: This looks very similar to your question that was closed earlier. Make a [mcve]. I think you got that advice last time too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your if's need braces

Your `if`s don't have curly braces after them. That's technically not wrong, but obviously not what you want and any way curly braces are encouraged as good style. C++ does **not** work with indentation, but with curly braces to form blocks of code.

For example in the first block:

```
if (str[0] == 's') {
    if (strlen(str)==9)
        arr[x-1][y-1]= arr[str[5] - '1'][str[4] - 'a'] + arr[str[8] - '1'][str[7] - 'a'];

    system("cls");
    print(arr);
    continue;
```

Without curly braces only the line `arr[x-1][y-1]=...` belongs to the `if`. The next three lines do *not* belong to the `if` and will be executed regardless of this condition. So if this piece of code is inside a loop it will *always* hit the `continue` and never progresss beyond that line.

So **always use curly braces after if** even it's only for good style. It helps you to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If the target question is "why this code wont work?" and the user inputs the string, so:

There are two cases with same length:

```
sum  s1:h12 (with 2 spaces)
```

and

```
sum s12:h12
```

You will not be able to recognize write case by string length only. I recommend you to use string parsing (stringstream or find ' ' and ':').